# Concatenating/Converting Multiple rows based on Customer #

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a report with a list of clients that will be having work performed by us the following week.

Currently, when the report runs, we generate a list of Clients, the dates of work to be performed, the type of work and their email address.

A lot of these clients have multiple services performed throughout that week, and as such, appear multiple times in the report.

I'd like to combine any clients that appear multiple times in the list to appear like this:

---

> What we currently have:

```
Cust ID  FName LName       Date      Description
   1     Jon   Smith     01/01/17   Spring Cleanup
   1     Jon   Smith     01/03/17   Lawn Maintenance
   1     Jon   Smith     01/05/17   Irrigation
   2     Jane  Roberts   01/02/17   Spring Cleanup
   2     Jane  Roberts   01/03/17   Lawn Maintenance
   3     Jim   Whoever   01/04/17   Turf
```

---

> What we'd like:

```
Cust ID  FName Lname       Date       Description
   1     Jon   Smith     01/01/17    Spring Cleanup, Lawn Maintenance, Irrigation
   2     Jane  Roberts   01/02/17    Spring Cleanup, Lawn Maintenance
   3     Jim   Whoever   01/04/17    Turf
```

Here's what we have for code so far:

```
Select 
    cust.CustID,
    cust.CustName, 
    cust.FirstName, 
    cust.LastName, 
    cust.Email, 
    wo.ShortDesc,
    wos.StartTime, 
    br.Description Branch

From 
    WorkOrderSchedules wos Join
    WorkOrders wo On wo.SvcOrderID = wos.SvcOrderID Join
    Customers cust On cust.CustID = wo.CustID Join
    Branches br On br.LocationID = wo.LocationID

Where 
  wos.StartTime Between DateAdd(wk, 2, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 7,
  GetDate()), -1)) And DateAdd(wk, 2, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 7, GetDate()),
  5)) And cust.CustName Not Like 'Three C%' And wo.ShortDesc Not Like
  'sales lead' And wo.ShortDesc Not Like '%lawn main%' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Port' And cust.CustName Not Like '31 Mile%' And
  cust.CustName Not Like '32 Mile' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Quail Ridge' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Hayes' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Inla' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Eaton' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Fisher' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Pasadena' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Mallard'

Group By
    cust.CustID,
    cust.CustName, 
    cust.FirstName, 
    cust.LastName, 
    cust.Email, 
    wo.ShortDesc,
    wos.StartTime, 
    br.Description

Order By 
    cust.CustName, 
    wos.StartTime
```

Thank you for any help in advance as I'm very new to SQL and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is emulating GROUP CONCAT.

```
Select 
    cust.CustID,
    cust.CustName, 
    cust.FirstName, 
    cust.LastName, 
    cust.Email, 
    wo.ShortDesc,
    Min(wos.StartTime) as StartTime, 
    --br.Description Branch
    Branch = STUFF((
                  SELECT ',' + md.Description
                  FROM dbo.Branches md
                  WHERE br.LocationID = md.LocationID
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
From 
    WorkOrderSchedules wos Join
    WorkOrders wo On wo.SvcOrderID = wos.SvcOrderID Join
    Customers cust On cust.CustID = wo.CustID Join
    Branches br On br.LocationID = wo.LocationID

Where 
  wos.StartTime Between DateAdd(wk, 2, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 7,
  GetDate()), -1)) And DateAdd(wk, 2, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 7, GetDate()),
  5)) And cust.CustName Not Like 'Three C%' And wo.ShortDesc Not Like
  'sales lead' And wo.ShortDesc Not Like '%lawn main%' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Port' And cust.CustName Not Like '31 Mile%' And
  cust.CustName Not Like '32 Mile' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Quail Ridge' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Hayes' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Inla' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Eaton' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Fisher' And
  cust.CustName Not Like 'Pasadena' And cust.CustName Not Like 'Mallard'
group by
    cust.CustID,
    cust.CustName, 
    cust.FirstName, 
    cust.LastName, 
    cust.Email, 
    wo.ShortDesc,
```

Comment: using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) +1.

Comment: Thanks! The column I'm looking to concatenate based on cust.custID is actually the workorders.shortdesc. I tried to replace the fields in the STUFF clause I end up with a few weird things.  The shortdesc field repeats the desc over and over & the rows being affected do not concatenate when trying to bring multiple rows together based on custID.
Here's what I have

Shortdesc = STUFF((
                  SELECT ',' + wo.ShortDesc 
                  FROM WorkOrders
                  WHERE wo.CustID=cust.CustID
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

Comment: You are aliasing the join to the outer query versus the inner one. leave the alias as md and see what happens. `STUFF((
                  SELECT ',' + md.ShordDesc
                  FROM dbo.WorkOrders md
                  WHERE cust.CustID = md.CustID
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')`

Comment: I just tried that and seem to be having the same issue.  The rows don't concatenate and the ShortDesc seems to repeat the same 3 items over and over.  Very confused as to why this is happening, thank you again for the guidance!

Comment: Remove the date column and see what happens